# Acid-catalyzed epoxide opening

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols

For the acid catalyzed opening of epoxides, the epoxide is first protonated to form the oxonium ion. I read in some textbooks that the $\ce{H2O}$ molecule, which acts as a nucleophile attacks in a $\mathrm{S_N2}$ concerted mechanism. Given that $\ce{H2O}$ is a weak nucleophile, how can a $\mathrm{S_N2}$ concerted mechanism be possible,  8 instead of $\mathrm{S_N1}$ which is expected of $\ce{H2O}$?

Also, for an unsymmetrical epoxide, why will the nucleophile attack at the more substituted $\ce{C}$?

Comment: Take a look in Organic Chemistry by Clayden & Warren, the whole thing is fully explained (as it probably is in any good organic textbook).

Comment: I can only find the base catalyzed epoxide opening, but not the acid catalyzed reaction.

Comment: https://chem.libretexts.org/Textbook_Maps/Organic_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Map%3A_Organic_Chemistry_With_a_Biological_Emphasis_(Soderberg)/Chapter_08%3A_Nucleophilic_substitution_reactions_I/8.6%3A_Epoxides_as_electrophiles_in_nucleophilic_substitution_reactions This link might help.